# Array.lenght = undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the folowing code:

```
var transitionsSettingsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("transitionsSettings");   
var myLenght = transitionsSettingsClass.lenght;   
alert(myLenght);
```

and I am getting undefinded alert. However if I use:

```
alert(transitionsSettingsClass[0])
```

then I get a clear ressult. I am trying to use this script so it would `setAttribute` in every tag with classname transitionsSettings and I need a lenght of array for using loop (for).

Comment: You mean "length", not "lenght".

Comment: Oh, this stupid mistake from me. Sorry for posting it here but I havent seen this mistake in my code. You can post it as an answer James and I will accept your answer so you will get reputation.

Comment: @horin - It's ok, the rep doesn't bother me. Feel free to accept any of the other answers that you feel is most helpful! No point in me cluttering it all up with another answer that's just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return a `NodeList` , like an array but not an array.

And it also has a property which is `length`

Answer (score 4):

lenght = length!!

So there you go!